# How to get the length of an arbitrary path in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have an arbitrary path in tikz (like in the following example). How can I get the arc length of the path and store it in a macro for later use?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,3) (4,7) (-2,9)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Using @Symbol1's comment, I was able to get the path length but didn't manage to transfer it outside of the decoration to use it in other places of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}   

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[decoration={
  markings,
  mark=
  at position 0 cm 
  with
  {
    \draw (0,0) circle (0pt) node[right]{\pgfdecoratedpathlength};
    %\def{\PathLength}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
  }
},
postaction=decorate
  ] plot[hobby] coordinates {(0,0) (1,3) (4,7) (-2,9)};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  %The length of the path is $\PathLength$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The decoration library has the infrastructure. For instance `\pgfdecoratedpathlength`.

Comment: @Symbol1: How can I use this in my specific example?

Comment: Maybe `\xdef`? Let me test some shortcuts floating in my head.

Comment: No doesn't work, I already tried `\xdef` and `\pgfmathsetmacro` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt using `\pgfextra`. Not sure if it is the most elegant solution.

```
\documentclass{article}   

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=
        at position 0 cm 
        with
        {
          \draw (0,0) circle (0pt)
            \pgfextra{\xdef\PathLength{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}} 
            node[right] {\pgfdecoratedpathlength};
        }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  ] 
    plot[hobby] coordinates {(0,0) (1,3) (4,7) (-2,9)};
\end{tikzpicture}

The length of the path is \PathLength.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepgfmodule{decorations}% This is enough. But any decoration library works
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \makeatletter
    \path plot[smooth] coordinates {(2,2) (1,3) (4,7) (-2,9)}
        \pgfextra{
            The easiest way to smuggle the current softpath
            \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\student@softpath
            \global\let\student@softpath = \student@softpath
        }
    ;
    You can backup the soft path if you want to
    \let\teacher@softpath = \student@softpath
    
    Compute the Length
    \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\student@softpath\dummy@token@to@hold@parsed@path
    \message{^^J^^J Public Service Announcement ^^J^^J}
    \message{^^J^^J arc length \pgf@decorate@totalpathlength pt ^^J^^J}
    \node[align=center]{arc length\\\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength pt};
    
    Reuse the path
    (student copy is destroyed by parsing, must use teacher copy)
    \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\teacher@softpath
    \pgfsyssoftpath@flushcurrentpath
    \pgfsys@stroke
    
    Put the softpath back like nothing happens
    \draw[red,thick,dotted]\pgfextra{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\teacher@softpath};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```